# Show modal/loading screen while gridview and AD query running on page load

Tags: gridview, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender

I have been all over the web looking at tons of examples, but they all seem to be tied to a button or some other event.  I have a page (Default) that loads data into a gridview and then checks the user accounts in each record to see if it exists in AD.  Depending on the amount of staged accounts this can take a minute.  Not that I care, but the customer doesnt want a blank screen while it is loading.  I know this is possible, but I have failed to get the code right that I have used from the internet.  I know this is probably redundant, but could anyone point me in the right direction?  I am using C# ASP.NET in VS 2010.

Thanks
EFD

Answer (score 0):

You can use UpdatePanels:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" runat="server" updatemode="always">
    <ContentTemplate>
      code here...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

add a div that shows an Image or "Please wait" Text and a Modal Popupextender to show that div:

```html
<div id="AlertDiv" class="Progress" style="display: none;">
  <img alt="progress" src="images/progress.gif"/ height="40" width="40" />     
</div>
    <asp:Button ID="hidIsNewPageLoad" runat="server" style="display:none; " />
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        runat="server"
        PopupControlID="AlertDiv"
        id="modalProgress" 
        TargetControlID = "hidIsNewPageLoad"
         />
```

finally, add Javascript to show/hide the buttons during loading:

```js
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $find('modalProgress').show();
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $find('modalProgress').hide();
}
$(document).ready(NewLoad);
function NewLoad()
{ Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
```